# How to import "chesterish" theme from Jupyter Notebook to JupyterLab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

How do I add the "chesterish" theme from Jupyter Notebook (`jt -t chesterish`) to JupyterLab? I have found other Dark themes ([here](https://github.com/mauhai/awesome-jupyterlab#themes)),([here](https://github.com/arbennett/jupyterlab-themes)), but I cannot seem to find chesterish anywhere for Jupyter Lab.